# javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet missing

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat9

I've read that Tomcat 9 needs Servlet 4.0, but wanted to make sure that is was the correct jar file to download. I'm trying to remove error messages from my application. Is this the jar file listed below the correct file?

Error Messages:
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet missing... or ...The type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved

Download site: https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-4-final-spec/index.html
Download file: JSR-000369 Java Servlet 4.0 Final Release javadoc -> javax.servlet-api-4.0-FINAL-javadoc.jar

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's the wrong JAR file. That JAR file only contains Javadocs.

The correct JAR file will be in Tomcat's `lib` directory.